# how completely clear your cache in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, nginx, apc

I run these commands:

`php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear// или (s)
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache`

But the final cache is cleared only after the reboot nginx and php5-fpm

Comment: If you are looking for more solutions to the topic then visit this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610198/clear-all-cache-in-laravel-with-artisan

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan config:cache` doesn't clear cache, but [creates config cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/configuration#configuration-caching). If you'll run first 4 commands from your list, all app cache will be cleared.

You may also want to clear cache, created by packages or composer or web server, it depends on what are you trying to achieve.

If you want to clear nginx cache, you can do this by deleting nginx cache directory, for example `/var/nginx/cache/`.

Comment: Pages are cached until you reboot nginx, i want to cler all cache

Comment: @bleggleb, you can delete nginx cache by deleting nginx cache directory, for example `/var/nginx/cache/`. Also, you can temporarily turn off caching if you want.