# Clear all cache in Laravel with artisan

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following error every time I try to clear the cache in Laravel 7.

```
Class 'App\Providers\TranslationServiceProvider' not found
```

I removed my provider but it still exists in the cache. I don't want to remove manually directory `/bootstrap/cache`. Does exist any artisan command which will take care of flushing all cache without any error?

I have already tried without any effect:

```
artisan config:cache
artisan config:clear
artisan cache:clear
artisan optimize
```

Comment: Did you tried composer update ?

Answer (score 13):

Clear All, run:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

result:

```
Cached events cleared! 
Compiled views cleared! 
Application cache cleared! 
Route cache cleared! 
Configuration cache cleared! 
Compiled services and packages files removed! 
Caches cleared successfully!
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `composer dump-autoload` to clear the providers cache

Comment: Please either put some explanation in your answer, or post this as a comment

Comment: The same error and more `Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1`

Answer (score 2):

### Proper way

Check if `/projectroot/app/Providers/TranslationServiceProvider.php` class exists with the minimum content of:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

class TranslationServiceProvider {}
```

Create this file if you don't have it. Then run `php artisan config:cache` to check if the error has been gone.

### Hacky way

Open `bootstrap/services.php` file and search for `App\Providers\TranslationServiceProvider` and remove the full line where you see it.

### Finally after both ways

Go to `config/app.php`, find the line `App\Providers\TranslationServiceProvider.php` in `providers` and `aliases` arrays, where it exists and remove them.

Then run `php artisan config:cache` again to cache the services without having that reference. If everything goes correct, you may safely delete the file which you've created at the first step (if you've used the proper method).

Comment: This provider exists only in cache files, i.e. `bootstrap/cache/config.php`. I don't understand why `php artisan config:cache` doesn't remove this file.

Comment: Because it can't run as it depends on the config file which is failing. You create the dummy file to make it past the config loading, then properly remove it.

Comment: That happens everytime when you delete a file before removing the references from the code. Mostly when uninstalling packages you've added the provider to config/app.php by hand. Always happens.

Comment: It depends on the cache of config, because proper config file is without this provider. Doesn't exist any artisan command to work around it?

Comment: The "proper" way is to run `composer dump-autoload` that deletes the cached providers file through the post-dump-autoload step from `Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump` since that is not working (meaning things have gone too bad) then just deleting the bootstrap/cache/services.php file should work

Comment: @apokryfos yes you're right. That's my way. And I mostly fixed this issue with what I've described above since L5.2. It made 3 fixing methods with yours. How lucky is the OP, right?

Comment: @Jsowa sorry I didn't see your comment asking for a proper artisan command to fix this. No. Since artisan depends on the config file, any artisan command will fail since the config is corrupt. You should fix this without artisan.

Answer (score 2):

Clearing All Cache
To clear all Laravel's cache, just run the following command

php artisan optimize:clear

There are several ways to empty the Laravel cache because it has distinct caches for different portions of your application.

1.Clearing Configuration Cache:php artisan config:clear

2.Clearing Route Cache:php artisan route:clear

3.Clearing View Cache:php artisan view:clear

4.Clearing Events Cache:php artisan event:clear

5.Clearing Application Cache:php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 1):

I created one route in web.php

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
    return redirect()->back();
});
```

---

And, added the route at the blade file. When I require to clear the cache, I do click on the clear cache button, it clears all cache, and get back me to the previous webpage. You may try it!

Answer (score 1):

Removing items from the cache programmatically is as easy as clearing the cache via the artisan command. In addition, you can use the Cache facade to access the cache or use the cache helper.

```php
Cache::flush()
cache()->flush()
```

Comment: there are a number of different caches in laravel and this solves a few of them but does not take all into concideration.