# Eloquent returning old data even after updating while data in database is updated

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I updated my data, the data in my database is updated, but when I fetch/show using eloquent the data still look like the old one. How is that happened, and what should I do?

Here is my code:

```
$dokumen = Dokumen::where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        
$dokumen->no_bl = $request->input('no_bl');
        
$tgl = $request->input('eta_vessel');
        
if(isset($tgl))
{

  $explode = explode(",",$tgl);
                       
  $merge = $explode[0] . $explode[1];
    
  $conv = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($merge));
            
  $dokumen->eta_vessel = $conv;  
}
       
$dokumen->vessel_name = $request->input('vessel_name');
    
$dokumen->save();
```

I changed the data like this:

[image]

when I saved, it's not changed:

[image]

while in my database, it's updated:

[image]

I have checked my code and nothing looks suspicious.

here is my view

```html
@foreach($jo as $rs)

@if($rs->id_status == 7)

@if($rs->order_status == 0)

<tr>

<td>{{$rs->id}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->no_jo}}</td>

<td><?php echo custom_date($rs->ori_date) ?></td>

<td>{{@$rs->customer->nama}}</td>

<td>{{@$rs->orders->nama}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->no_aju_pib}}</td>

<td>{{@$rs->doc->no_bl}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->cbm}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->kgs}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->pkgs}} {{$rs->satuan_pkgs}}</td>

<td>{{$rs['20ft']}}</td>

<td>{{$rs['40ft']}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->tipe_pengiriman}}</td>

<td><?php echo custom_date(@$rs->doc->eta_vessel) ?></td>

<td>{{@$rs->doc->vessel_name}}</td>

<td>{{$rs->shiper}}</td>

<td>{{@$rs->fwd->nama}}{{$rs->forwarder}}</td>



<td class="text-center">

    <ul class="icons-list">

        <li class="dropdown">

            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">

                <i class="icon-menu9"></i>

            </a>



            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">

                <li><a href="{{ url('admin/jo/details'.'/'.$rs->id) }}"><i class="icon-search4"></i> Details</a></li>

                <?php if($rs->order_status == 0){ ?>

                <li><a href="{{ url('admin/jo/ot'.'/'.$rs->id) }}"><i class="icon-check"></i> Order Trucking</a></li>

                <?php }?>

                

                <li><a href="{{ url('admin/jo/edit'.'/'.$rs->id) }}"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Edit</a></li>
                
                <li>{!! Form::open(['url' => ['admin/jo/cancelJo/'.$rs->id],'id'=>'cancel-jo','method' => 'POST','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}<button type="submit" name="id" value="{{$rs->id}}"><i class="icon-cross">Cancel JO</i></button>{!! Form::close() !!}</li>

                <li><a href="#" id='delete' data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a></li>

            </ul>

        </li>

    </ul>

</td>

</tr>

@endif

@endif

@endforeach
```

Comment: Clear laravel cache. Are you using any caching package?

Comment: Also, how you're fetching the data from the database for showing/viewing purpose? Add that part of code too.

Comment: BTW, you should use ``$dokumen = Dokumen::find($id);`` instead of ``$dokumen = Dokumen::where('id', '=', $id)->first();``

Comment: its already on server how can i clear laravel cache in that condition?

Comment: i have updated my showing code, please check it if you dont mind

Comment: and how you're passing the data to view? I mean add your controller method code part too.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65610198/clear-all-cache-in-laravel-with-artisan for clearing cache data

Comment: i called it through another table which have relation using eloquent, but its not up to date to changes, this part when i called it @$rs->doc->no_bl

Comment: i have tried to clear cache, but still not change anything